# Property of Dual Norm for a General Banach Space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, vector-spaces, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $E$ be a Banach space. Let $f \in E^*$. The dual norm is defined:

$$||f|| = \sup_{x \in E,\ ||x|| \leq 1} |\langle f , x\rangle |$$

Claim: We can find some $x \in E$ such that $||x|| = 1$, and $\langle f , x\rangle \geq \frac{1}{2} ||f||$.

Note that $E$ is a general vector space over some field $F$, not necessarily the reals. I have not come across this property before and an unsure how to prove it for a general field. Any hints appreciated.

Comment: What about first proving that $\sup_{\|x\|\le 1}=\sup_{\|x\|=1}$ then using the definition of supremum?

Comment: I will try this. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If $\|f\|=0$ then $f=0$ and we can take any unit vector $x$. Otherwise $\frac 1 2 \|f\| <\|f\|$ so (by definition of $\|f\|$) there exists $y$ such that $\|y\| \leq 1$ and $\langle f,y \rangle \geq \frac 1 2 \|f\|$. Let $x=\frac 1 {\|y\|} y$. Then $\langle f,x \rangle = \frac 1 {\|y\|} \langle f,y \rangle\geq \frac 1 2 \|f\|$.

Comment: Since the vector space is not necessarily over the real numbers, we don't know if your $x$ is still in $E$

Comment: @DavidHughes Wait a moment, if it is not over the reals then what does $\sup\langle f,x\rangle$ mean (if it is not a real number)? Should it be $\sup|\langle f,x\rangle|$ instead?

Comment: What is the definiton of the norm? Does $\|cx\|=|c|\|x\|$ makes sense if $c$ comes from an arbitrary field?

Comment: Fixed the definition of the norm

Comment: It may be that the vector space is actually implied to be a real vector space. I've just checked that, for the definition of linear functionals, it is given that $E$ is over the reals. Just to make sure, does this problem only make sense of $E$ is a real or complex vector space?

Comment: Yes, it makes sense only for real/complex scalars.